# Programmatically copying data across tables in different sql server databases having different schemas

Tags: c#, database, ado.net, sql-server-2012

I am trying to build a system which takes in snapshot of a few related tables in a SQL Server database, attaches a date-time element to it and is stored in a different database. Hence the new database contains snapshots of data at different date-times (leading to different schemas).

I have already got it working using t-sql on Sql Server Management Studio. Can I write a query in C# and execute it between the two databases? I read about ADO.NET but couldn't find a way of establishing two SQLconnections and then executing query for the transfer.

Are there more efficient ways to do this? I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably start reading [the Wikipedia page about ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load).

Also, if you wish to [perform ETL in pure C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34556/Write-ETL-jobs-in-pure-C), you may give a look at stuff like [Rhino ETL](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-etl).

Answer (score 0):

You should put your query in a stored procedure. Then it is trivial to call from Management Studio, C#, or any other program / interface. A simple example:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- your query
END
GO
```

Then from C# (assuming the stored procedure does not return any results):

```cs
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "dbo.foo";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

This is not an exhaustive code sample (no error handling, disposal etc.) but just to give an idea.

**EDIT**

You should create a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) between your two SQL Server instances. Then your query can say something like:

```
SELECT * INTO [linkedserver].database.dbo.tablename
  FROM dbo.whatever
  -- WHERE ... ;
```

This will be much more efficient than pulling the data into C#.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, but are there more efficient techniques? I am working on tables having about a million entries. I read about sqlbulkcopy but couldn't figure out how to use it with tables having different schemas.

Comment: SqlBulkCopy is used to copy large blocks of data into your program and then elsewhere. Why do you think that would be more efficient than just having SQL Server do it internally? Can you show the query you're using as a part of the question? You did say you already have it working, so if you just want to call this query from C#, again, I'd suggest the most efficient way to do that is to put the query in  a stored procedure, and call it from C# that way. Pulling the data into C# is wasteful and is never going to be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks again Aaron, now I have better insight into solution to the problem. Your solution worked perfectly well.